# CakePHP Routes: Isolating passed parameters in strings

Tags: cakephp, routes

I'm trying to set up routing for my CakePHP application.

One example of a URL I want is `/:slug-c-:id/`. (EG `example.com/foo-c-1/`)

This URL is supposed to have two passed parameters: `:slug` and `:id`.
However, CakePHP sees the two parameters as `:slug-c` and `:id`.

I tried separating the route like this `:slug\-c-:id`, but then when I use the HTML helper to build a URL, it includes the `\` in the string it builds. (EG `example.com/foo\-c-1/`

Is there another way to separate passed parameters from other strings? Something like PHP's `This is a string with a {$var}adjacent to letters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a somewhat hacky solution that I'd rather not use, but basically I set up my route as:

`/:slug-:cslug-:id/*` and set `:cslug`'s regular expression to `c`

The problem with this is every time I set up a URL with HTML helper I have to do

```
array(
   'controller' => 'products'
   'action' => 'index'
   'slug' => 'Foo'
   'cslug' => 'c'
   'id' => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

make it `/:slug-:id/` and set the regex for slug to include that '-c'.

I'm not entirely sure you can set greedy regex for slug with an id at the end. Also, if you use Inflector to create slug (which is the recommended way), it would create slug with underscores. So I think it's better to use '_c' instead. The regex should be something along the line `[A-Za-z0-9_]+_c`

More here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration